# Restore view in NetBeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans

Unfortunately I closed one view option in NetBeans IDE.

How can I restore this? (red rectangle)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0DDf.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the "View" menu, "Show Breadcrumbs"

Comment: Thanks. It was that